# How can I upload a Python project on web/server with all its dependencies?

Tags: python, selenium, server, upload, hosting

I tried to make an automation script using Selenium which automates my timelog that I've to fill everyday. It's working fine locally, but only I can use it in my organization.

I can share the script, but others will have to configure their system for Python, pip, Selenium and also the environment variables which is not easy for everyone.

Is there a way I can upload my script on web and create a virtual environment with all the required packages, and other can run that script from there?